# Internet Explorer 10 css3 transition height not happening with parent padding-bottom value

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have a container div which in order to make it fluid in relation with the width of the window (and keep square proportions) has the following css:

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/m178sazh/)

```
#container {
    width:30%;
    height:0;
    padding-bottom:30%;
    position: relative;
}
```

it has an inner div with a fixed height and width that should become 100% (both) with a transition when hovering:

```
#inside {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
    -o-transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
    transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
}

#container:hover #inside {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

In Chrome,Firefox,Opera,Safari there is no problem. Internet Explorer 10 however, doesnt transitions the height value, so there is a jump.
Is there a way I can solve this for ie10 without touching the structure of the divs (padding-bottom in parent div)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making the following changes to `#inside`:

- Add `min-width: 30px;` and `min-height: 30px;`
- Change `width: 30px;` to `width: 1%;` and `height: 30px;` to `height: 1%;`

```css
#container:hover #inside {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#container {
    background: black;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
}
#inside {
    background: pink;
    height: 1%;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 30px;
    min-width: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
    -o-transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
    transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
    width: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="out" id="container">
    <div id="inside"></div>
</div>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/r8rjhy9v/

Answer (score 2):

For IE 10...

After some considerable experimentation I've come to the following conclusions:

1. using `calc()` with the `height:` property causes IE10 to at least
   ignore the `transition-property:height` effect.
2. the `max-height:`property acts as a mask, where the size of the element is really what the `height:` property declares it to be but only up to the `max-height:` property size is visible.
3. the `transition-property:height` effect starts from the full `height:` of
   the element (this is noticeable as a lag as the hidden part of the
   element transitions under the mask)
4. you need to use both `height:` and `max-height:` to get `transition-property:height` to work at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/Neoheurist/5ax5o1ge

HTML

```
<div class='accordion'>
    <section class='sash greedy'>
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.accordion {
    background:black;
    height:10.0em;
}

.accordion .sash {
    background:red;

    height:2.0em;
    max-height:calc(100% - 2em);
    transition-property:height;
    transition-duration:1000ms;
}

.accordion .sash.greedy:hover {
    max-height:calc(100% - 2em);
    height:100%;
}
```